# How to create a "select" custom property?

Tags: 2010, web-part, web-config

In a Webpart I want to set some customs properties. I have this code

```
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), WebBrowsable(true), WebDisplayName("myName"), WebDescription("myDescription"), Category("myCategory")]
        public string MyProperty
        {
            get { return _myProperty; }
            set { _myProperty= value; }
        }
```

that it renders a input text in the config menu. Since here its all ok.

But now I need to render another property as a select with 2 o 3 options. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare an `enum` in your webpart and expose that as property. An enum will be rendered as a dropdown in the properties toolpane. If you need more complicated behavior you need to create a custom ToolPart.

```
//create enum
public enum MyColorEnum {
  Red = 0,
  Blue,
  Yellow
};

protected MyColorEnum _color;

[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User), WebBrowsable,
 WebDisplayName("Color"), WebDescription("Color")]
public MyColorEnum Color
{
  get { return _color; }
  set { _color = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom [ToolPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.toolpart%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for your WebPart.
Here is an example: http://sharepoint-insight.blogspot.com/2008/10/sharepoint-creating-web-part-with.html